# Why do people define variables in render() from state properties in React?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, ecmascript-6

In React, if a class has a state of:

```
state = {
   cat: "Siamese"
}
```

Why do people redefine it under render() like this:

```
render() {
  const {cat} = this.state
  return <p>{cat}</p>
}
```

rather than just referring to it as this.state.cat?

Is there a performance improvement or something else?

Comment: it just looks better, more readable and shorter

Comment: ...and makes some further refactoring(like say [lifting state up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html)) much easier to implement

Answer (score 1):

This line of code

```
const {cat} = this.state
```

Is destructor syntax. It's simply take the `cat` state from `this.state` . So you dont have to write `this.state.cat` every time inside render function but just simply use `cat`

Answer (score 1):

```
const {cat} = this.state
```

It's called [object destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Object_destructuring).

It's way flexible if you have many fields in your `state` or `props` object.

something like:

```
const { cat, dog, ...otherAnimals } = this.state;
```

Answer (score 0):

The concept of object destructuring is an es6 feature which enables the user to use the properties of an object.In this case you are using the state object for destructring.

example without destructuring:

```
state={cat:'meaow',dog:'bark'}

render(){
return(
      <div>
      <h2>{this.state.cat}</h2>
      <h2>{this.state.dog}</h2>
      </div>)
}
```

example with destructuring:

```
state={cat:'meaow',dog:'bark'}

render(){
const {cat,dog}=this.state
return(
      <div>
      <h2>{cat}</h2>
      <h2>{dog}</h2>
      </div>)
}
```